# WSO2 APIM 3.0.0: Issue when updating clientsecret in devportal

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using devportal in the 3.0.0 version and I am using a separated instance for Keymanager.
In Keymanager, in the service provider admin_admin_store when I refresh the clientsecret, I notice that the devportal instance will always use the old clientsecret and not the new one.

After looking into APIMGT database, I notice that devportal is reading the consumer secret from the table AM_SYSTEM_APPS and that the Keymanager is writing the new consumer secret in the table IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS.

Do I misconfigured something or is it a bug ?

Comment: Did you regenerate secret for any specific reason?

Comment: No, I would like to be sure that this is working before I go live :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we regenerate any system apps (eg:admin_publisher) used for API Manager portals, the client secret needs to be manually edited in the AM_SYSTEM_APPS table in the corresponding row. Currently automatically updating the table is not supported.

Comment: Thanks. Would be a nice and useful feature in a next release maybe :-)